# Pages (.php) stop loading include files

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have a static site with 20 or so pages built with mostly html & some php. Each page has this line of code below to include the meta/header stuff, which is placed inside the /tmpl/ folder. Everything was working ok, but suddenly today the include content stop loading, the body text of the pages still show.

I haven't made any changes for months. I've checked and all the files are intact with old date stamp, and the hosting company (Register.com) said they didn't make any changes. Do you know what might have happened and how to fix?

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmpl/header.php');
```

Comment: what is the error message you get ?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console in your browser? You'd need to look for any 400-level or higher response codes. You probably also want to use the inspection tool - if you see PHP code in the file your browser's displaying, that would indicate that the PHP module was disabled.

Comment: No error message. The body content still displays, but no CSS, js files are loaded because those files were linked from the header.php

Comment: Check `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns the right path to the folder that contains the `tmpl` folder. Also, check the user PHP is running under has the right permissions to read such file.

For debugging purposes, changing `include` by `require` and enabling `display_errors: on` can give you more details on the problem, or you can simply check PHP log files.

Comment: @danielperaza - Through the Control Panel File Manager hosting, I noticed the path: Root: /htdocs at the top. But $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns /usr/services/vux/apache/htdocs. Does it matter? I guess I should turn on display errors, just that it's a live site, I'm a little hesitant

Comment: Don't rely on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Use a relative path from the current script, eg `include __DIR__ . '/tmpl/header.php';`

Comment: @phil - Thanks, that's fixed it!!! What's the difference? I've been using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for years without issue until today

Comment: Well, everything in `$_SERVER` comes from some external source out of your control. There's no guarantee that it will be configured correctly or at all. It's best if your apps are portable and self-contained